# Can not get the function URL when deploying bitcoin-info-action to firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

I am deploying https://github.com/greenido/bitcoin-info-action with instructions from https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-action-on-google-with-webhook/#0

When I use the Webhook URL provided in the example, it works fine. When I build and deploy using the code myself for the webhook , it does not generate function URL.

Here are the steps:

1. Clone the Git Repo https://github.com/greenido/bitcoin-info-action
2. Do a firebase init Do a firebase deploy (install all modules as
   needed)
3. I have not changed the index.js , reviewed the answers at [Can't find the function url for Firebase webhook in Google Assistant tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46083838/cant-find-the-function-url-for-firebase-webhook-in-google-assistant-tutorial) and others.

I have checked the firebase console and functions on the left menu and I do not find a URL, instead instructions on deploy (same that I used )

Here is the output of firebase deploy:

```
[google-tester-mn1:~/soverflow/bitcoin-info-action-master ] $ /Users/google-tester/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/bin/firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'bitcoininfo-5cb78'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  hosting: preparing public directory for upload...
✔  hosting: 2 files uploaded successfully

✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/bitcoininfo-5cb78/overview
Hosting URL: https://bitcoininfo-5cb78.firebaseapp.com
```

Here is the output of deploy --only functions:

```
Deploying to 'bitcoininfo-5cb78'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

 ✔  Deploy complete!

 Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/bitcoininfo-5cb78/overview
```

Contents of the directory:

`[google-tester-mn1:~/soverflow/bitcoin-info-action-master/functions ] $ ls -l ~/soverflow/bitcoin-info-action-master
total 96
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 google-tester  google-tester   1642 Nov 16 17:04 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 google-tester  google-tester  11325 Nov 16 17:04 LICENSE
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 google-tester  google-tester   3255 Nov 16 17:04 README.md
-rw-r--r--@ 1 google-tester  google-tester    796 May  1  2017 agent.json
-rw-r--r--@ 1 google-tester  google-tester   3865 Nov 16 17:04 bitcoin-info-io17.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 google-tester  google-tester    134 Dec 29 11:42 firebase.json
drwxr-xr-x  6 google-tester  google-tester    204 Dec 29 12:31 functions
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 google-tester  google-tester   4411 Nov 16 17:04 index.js
drwxr-xr-x@ 7 google-tester  google-tester    238 Dec 29 11:39 intents
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 google-tester  google-tester    647 Nov 16 17:04 package.json
drwxr-xr-x  4 google-tester  google-tester    136 Dec 29 11:42 public
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 google-tester  google-tester   2476 Nov 16 17:04 webhook-example-bitcoin.php`

```
Again:
```

`[google-tester-mn1:~/soverflow/bitcoin-info-action-master/functions ]ls -l ~/soverflow/bitcoin-info-action-master/functions/
total 576
-rw-r--r--@   1 google-tester  google-tester    4411 Dec 29 12:23 index.js
drwxr-xr-x  124 google-tester  google-tester    4216 Dec 29 12:24 node_modules
-rw-r--r--    1 google-tester  google-tester  281603 Dec 29 12:24 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--    1 google-tester  google-tester     460 Dec 29 12:24 package.json`

Contents of package.json:

`{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^1.7.0",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.1"
  },
  "private": true
}`

I have all the node modules, including actions-on-google. There is no error about missing modules.

Comment: I think you should file an issue on the GitHub repo that you're working with.

Comment: Can you include the output of "firebase deploy" in your question, please?

Comment: @prisoner I added the output of firebase deploy

Comment: What is the output of `firebase deploy --only functions`?

Comment: What are the contents of functions/index.js? (Check and cut/paste.)

Comment: @Prisoner The index.js is exactly the same as https://raw.githubusercontent.com/greenido/bitcoin-info-action/master/index.js (Verified with diff)

Comment: What files and directories do you have in the `~/soverflow/bitcoin-info-action-master` directory?

Comment: @Prisoner Added the directory contents above

Comment: Excellent! Can we also see a list of the files and folders in the `~/soverflow/bitcoin-info-action-master/functions/` directory, please?

Comment: @Prisoner Updated with the contents of function

Comment: What are the contents of `~/soverflow/bitcoin-info-action-master/functions/package.json`?

Comment: @Prisoner Added the package.json file.

Comment: Thank you. Interesting... how about the results of `firebase --debug deploy --only functions`

Comment: Do you have a credit card info with Firebase? If not... it won't let you make external calls. 
The example I created for the code lab is using Google cloud functions.

Comment: @IdoGreen - He's not even getting it to deploy to Functions, from the output and what the console reports.

Comment: Aha! @IdoGreen's last comment contained the answer and I glossed right past it. Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code was written for Google Cloud Functions (GCF) (as Ido notes in his comment), while you're trying to deploy it with Cloud Functions for Firebase (CFF or GCFF). While CFF is built on top of GCF, there are some slight differences in how you register the function itself.

With GCF you need to:

1. Export the function
2. Upload the code to GCF (either using the `gcloud` command line tool or using the console)
3. If you used the console, add the function

While with GCFF you need to:

1. Require the `firebase-functions` library in your code (usually with something like `const functions = require('firebase-functions');`)
2. Export the results of `functions.https.onRequest(...)` in your code
3. Deploy with `firebase deploy`

I've submitted a pull request for Ido to change his code (https://github.com/greenido/bitcoin-info-action/pull/4) or you can just pull it from master at https://github.com/afirstenberg/bitcoin-info-action.

Comment: Prisoner (and Ido, Doug,Nick)  Thank you very much! It works perfectly

Comment: Excellent! Glad it helps! (Accepting and/or upvoting the answer is always appreciated if it has.)

Comment: (And I'm glad we finally figured it out!)

Comment: Glad it help!! I wasn't online too much in the past few days... so sorry for not giving a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your firebase console (with your web browser), the fulfillment URL is there too.